# Optimize multiple if conditions for flag check

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization

```
[Flags]
public enum PatternTypes
{
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 4,
  D = 8,
  E = 16,
  F = 32,
  G = 64
}
```

`patternsToFind` [this is **`PatternTypes`**]: it is contain flags value to find number of pattern like `A | B | E` that will return us `A, B and E` pattern result in list

```
if patternsToFind.HasFlag(A) {call patternA() and add result to list}
if patternsToFind.HasFlag(B) {call patternB() and add result to list}
if patternsToFind.HasFlag(C) {call patternC() and add result to list}
if patternsToFind.HasFlag(D) {call patternD() and add result to list}
if patternsToFind.HasFlag(E) {call patternE() and add result to list}
```

like this, I have 20 pattern so what should i use to optimize it? Alternate to multiple if conditions. Either i have to write it 20 times.

Comment: What is a "pattern"?

Comment: It would be great if you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @John in if condition i call function that return list of pattern object but i don't think its related to question so i just called it pattern

Comment: Include a `PatternTypes` property in your pattern class and add a `Matches` method, then you can look for patterns from a list that match `patternsToFind`.  Something like `foreach pattern ... if (pattern.Matches(patternsToFind)) ...`

Comment: If all `patternA-Z` method return the same type you can map the enum value to a `func<ReturnTypeOfPattern>` with a dictionary.

Comment: @xdtTransform yeah I hate switch statements alot of the time I just use dictionaries cuz they look nicer

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the defined values of an enum at runtime;

```cs
   foreach(PatternTypes value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PatternTypes))){
       if (patternsToFind.HasFlag(value)){
           // ...
       }
   }
```

Comment: And adding to this answer, you can have a dictionary where key is the flag and value is the object you need. So then in this foreach, if the flag exists, you get the object from dictionary.
Otherwise you will need if's to find the object anyway.

Comment: @Jeremy thank you but it will still required multiple if's conditions as i have to call different function for each pattern say `patternsToFind = A | B | C` then i will need to call  `patternA()`, `patternB()`, `patternC()` to find A, B and C patterns

Comment: Then add those `Func<..>`'s to a dictionary. Or generalise them based on a `value` parameter. Without seeing more code, I can't offer a better explanation.